# Swift and Firebase 3.x saving and retrieving data

Tags: swift, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm saving data in one view with the following code:

```
let item1:String = textfield.text!

if TextField1.text != "" {
    self.ref.child("userProfile").child((user!.uid)/value1Total").setValue(Double(item1)!)
}
```

What would be my code in a different view to set that saved value to a label?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below example:

```
let name = nameTextField.text

let user: NSDictionary = ["name":name!,"dob":dateOfBirthTimeInterval]

//add firebase child node
let profile = firebase.ref.childByAppendingPath(name!)

// Write data to Firebase
profile.setValue(user)
```

Have a look on it this [link](http://rshankar.com/ios-swift-firebase-demo/) for more info